# Registering a service worker, getting an error

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported

I am getting this error when I try to register the service worker.

Comment: Despite my answer, please provide a code snippet to assure there are no mistakes within.

Answer (score 0):

> Service workers are only available to "secure origins" (HTTPS sites, basically) in line with a policy to prefer secure origins for powerful new features. However http://localhost is also considered a secure origin, so if you can, developing on localhost is an easy way to avoid this error.

[More info here.](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq)